# Does "I leave her" have two meanings?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

I think that "I leave her" could have two meanings:

> 1. I cause her to leave.
> 2. I cause her to be left.

I think that sentence #1 is less common, but a valid interpretation. Am I correct?

Comment: *I leave her* cannot be used to mean "I cause her to leave". *I leave her X* means *I cause her to have X after I depart* (typically after my death, in my will).

Answer (score 2):

*Leave X* means:

- you are going away from X,
- you are not taking X with you if X is an object.
- if X is not specified it defaults to "where I'm at currently" - omitting X never refers to an object (you would have to say *leave it*).

*Leave X Y* (or *leave Y to/for X*) means:

- you are going away from Y,
- you are not taking Y with you (if Y is a place you have to say *at Y* or *in Y*),
- you are expecting X to take Y if Y is an object - if not at the moment you leave Y, sometime later when it is convenient or possible for X.

*Leave* never means *make or cause someone to leave*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have two meanings, just two variations of the same meaning.

> I *left* the bookstore (= I walked out of the bookstore)
>
> I *left her* by the bookstore (= I walked away from her)
>
> I *left the book* in the store (= I walked away from the book)

In each case, *I* am the one doing the action, not the object or person.  I think you may be confusing this with the passive voice "to be left"

> She *was left* by the bookstore (= she stayed while someone else walked away)
>
> The book *was left* in the store (= the book stayed while someone left)

If you want to indicate that *she* left, unwillingly, then you would say something like.

> I *made her leave* the bookstore.
>
> I *made her leave me* by the bookstore.
>
> I *made her leave* the book in the store.